# Restructure Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a python dataframe that I need to restructure to fit a use case.

The dataframe is as below:

```
index  | Probability
Value1 |  .98
Value2 |  .90
Value3 |  .85
Value4 |  .80
```

I need to restructure the dataframe as below with the first row being the headers:

```
Match1 | Probab1 | Match2 | Prob2 | Match3 | Prob3 | Match4 | Prob4 
Value1 | .98     | Value2 | .90   | Value2 | .85   | Value4 | .80
```

Is there an easy way to do this with Pandas and Python?

Comment: I think you are trying to transpose your DataFrame, or basically switch the columns with the rows. Try `df = df.T` and see if that helps. You may also need to rename some columns.

Comment: Nope, transposing puts the probabilities in the second row, I need them adjacent to the values.

Comment: A more complete example would help. Right now there are no 'Match' values in your DataFrame so it is unclear how to get them in your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

`stack` + `transpose` will get you what you want, with a little of renaming. If `index` is actually your index, just do `df = df.reset_index()`

```
import pandas as pd
print(df)
#    index  Probability
#0  Value1         0.98
#1  Value2         0.90
#2  Value3         0.85
#3  Value4         0.80

df = df.stack().reset_index()

# Rename things
df.loc[df.level_1 == 'index', 'level_1'] = 'Match' + (df.loc[df.level_1 == 'index', 'level_0']+1).astype('str')
df.loc[df.level_1 == 'Probability', 'level_1'] = 'Prob' + (df.loc[df.level_1 == 'Probability', 'level_0']+1).astype('str')

df = df.drop(columns='level_0').T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

`df` is now:

```
        0      1       2      3       4      5       6      7
0  Match1  Prob1  Match2  Prob2  Match3  Prob3  Match4  Prob4
1  Value1   0.98  Value2    0.9  Value3   0.85  Value4    0.8
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! The only edit that I had to make was add 'axis=1' to the drop command:

    df = df.drop(columns='level_0', axis=1).T